# How to find Width /length within the rectangle using angle of approach and height of the rectangle.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I need to calculate the width/length of the red line in the pic in a rectangle when we know the angle of approach and (from one target to another) and the height of the approach.  Please suggest.  Thanks.[image]

Comment: Is $H$ the distance from the bottom left corner of the rectangle to the red line, or is it the distance between the two corners of the rectangle?

Comment: H is the height of the blue rectangle.

Comment: Then there is not enough information. You could move the rectangle (causing $W$ to change) without changing any of the known quantities.